# What does this mean?

Tags: translation

お兄ちゃんには一番知られたくなかったかな

I'm confused. Google Translate says "I don't want brother to know the best", but I'm not convinced at all.

Comment: I would suggest adding what you think it should be and why.  Otherwise, it will be probably be closed because translation requests are off-topic.

Answer (score 4):

> お兄ちゃんには一番知られたくなかったかな

I guess my brother is the last person I wanted to let know (litt: I didn't want to be known by my brother the most)

Comment: For 一番, maybe a better rendition might be _"most"_ rather that _"first"_.

Comment: I agree, I edited